Which type of paint lasts longer on outdoor wooden decks?
Which type of paint lasts longer on outdoor wooden decks?



red-colored stain for wooden decks and front porches?

white-colored silicone-based roof coating mixed with red concrete colorant?




Does it get covered by snow and ice? what is the footfall?

Paint never lasts on decks, period. Either stain it or replace with PVC/composite decking.

Silicone paint is not intended for frequent foot traffic, only occasional cats and possums etc.
If you stay off the deck the silicone will probably last longer, else if it gets walked on the stain will last longer.
Longest lasting is probably some sort of 2k epoxy coating.

Agreed; a good deck stain is a better choice than paint for this application.

We use marine enamel for all rentals.    We sometimes repaint a deck on houses we are selling.    By far lasts longer for wood decks and quite frankly the boat paint manufacturers do a great job picking out default colors.   We did a rental in Duralux National Blue years ago...   The guy who has been renting with us says that at least twice a month people walking by ask him what kind of paint it is.
Marine enamel is one of maybe 10 "secrets" we do for fixing up houses.   Not only do these paints look great on a deck but they are easily touched up and the color matches way better than traditional deck/outdoor paints.    Also part of the secret is getting a default color and there are like 6-7 colors we use all the time.   Instead of worrying about big box mixing your paint with the right calibration (which is very very very off going from store to store or even the same store after a bit of time) this is done at a factory.
